# Excel Formula to Compare Zip Codes on separate worksheets

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, zip

I have an Excel worksheet containing a column with ZIP codes. On a second worksheet I have a column containing a huge list of ZIP codes and another column containing a list of sales territories associated with those ZIP codes. I need to compare a ZIP code in a cell on worksheet 1 with with the array of ZIP codes on worksheet 2, and if there is a match, I need to display the sales territory matching the ZIP code on worksheet 2 in a field on worksheet 1.

How can I do this?

Comment: Sounds like VLOOKUP()

Comment: Thanks Scott. I've been trying vlookup and match and index but the formulas don't return the sales territory from the column on the second worksheet.

Comment: Then you need to show us a mock up of the data and what formula you have tried.  Because one of those should work.

Comment: This is the first time using Super User for me. I'm trying to copy the field information from the worksheet to show a mock of the data but it only imports the information as concatenated text.

Comment: =VLOOKUP(G2,Sheet2!D:D,Sheet2!E:E,0) THIS IS AN EXAMPLE OF WHAT I HAVE TRIED In hopes that if the zip code in cell g2 matches a zip code found on sheet 2 in the column range D. The hope is that if it finds a match it will display the territory name from sheet 2 column E into a column on sheet one.

Comment: `=VLOOKUP(G2,Sheet2!D:E,2,0)`

Comment: Thanks so much for working through this with me Scott. The formula keeps returning #N/A

Comment: Then it is not finding a match.  the match must be identical.  Check the data, make sure both are either text or both are number.  Then make sure there are no extra characters like spaces or other non printable characters that may cause Excel not see them as matches.

Comment: You are correct Scott. The information I have is incomplete on the second worksheet. I've gone back to the person who is requesting the information to provide complete information. Thank you VERY much for your help.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it became apparent that the issue is about completeness of the data and not Excel related.

Answer (score -1):

*Rather than simple Lookup, you need an `Array (CSE) formula` to compare Zip Codes between Sheets, to get Sales area.*

[image]

- Formula in Cell `B9` of `Sheet1`:

  ```
  {=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!$E$9:$E$16, SMALL(IF(Sheet2!$D$9:$D$16=$A9,ROW(Sheet2!$E$9:$E$16)-ROW(Sheet2!$E$9)+1),COLUMNS($B9:B9))),"")}
  ```

**N.B.**

- Finish the formula with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter** & fill down.
- *Adjust Sheet Name & Cell references in the Formula as needed.*

Comment: Write your concern that why this has been down voted !!